# Error page without using web.xml

Tags: java, spring

Without response object how to give an error page without using web.xml.

Comment: Are we being quizzed?

Comment: and without web app? ;)

Comment: What do you mean without response object? Like no `HttpSerlvetResponse`?

Comment: no, it is obviously there but not in the same class we are handling the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the comments you are encountering an error situation in a method that does not have a reference to the `HttpServletResponse` object. Presumably one invoked (possibly indirectly) by a servlet or JSP page.

What you need to do in that situation is to throw an Exception. If no checked exceptions will fit then you could throw an `IllegalStateException` or any subclass of `RuntimeException` (possibly creating your own).

Proper handling of the error will need to handle elsewhere in code that is aware of the `HttpServletResponse`. If you throw a custom Exception it should be fairly easy to catch it higher up.

Answer (score 1):

@dave...

You can write errors in jsp....

1) error.jsp
2) errorPage.jsp

In errorPage.jsp you can add below tag

1. <%@ page isErrorPage="true" import="java.io.*" %>

In error.jsp you can add below tag

1. <%@page errorPage="errorPage.jsp" %>